# WPF : Barcode font bug?

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts, barcode

**SITUATION**

-I have created a folder "Fonts" in my WPF application, and added 5 fonts as you can see.

-Then i have added the fonts in my Resources .

[image]

XAML(I have tried to write pack:app,,,.. to but it doesnt help)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <FontFamily x:Key="Default">/Design/Fonts/#arial</FontFamily>
  <FontFamily x:Key="Rounded">/Design/Fonts/#BUNGASAI</FontFamily>
  <FontFamily x:Key="BarcodeCode39">/Design/Fonts/#Code39r</FontFamily>
  <FontFamily x:Key="Barcode3of9X">/Design/Fonts/#FRE3OF9X</FontFamily>
  <FontFamily x:Key="Barcode3of9">/Design/Fonts/#FREE3OF9</FontFamily>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**PROBLEM**

The thing is it work perfectly for Arial and Bungasai  or for other normal fonts, but whenever i try to use those "barcode"-fonts then it shows the arial one.

**MAYBE RELEVENT INFOS**

thats how i use my fonts in

XAML

Doesnt work:

```
<TextBlock Name="BarcodeContent"
           FontFamily="{StaticResource BarcodeCode39}"/>
```

Works perfectly:

```
<TextBlock Name="BarcodeContent"
           FontFamily="{StaticResource Rounded}"/>
```

Comment: Not an answer for your issue, but for barcodes you should consider using some libraries like zxing.net.

Comment: You use the name of the font rather than the file name. Right click the ttf and look for full name. Also, relative paths for font files will result in a memory leak. No drive letter means those paths are relative.

Comment: @Andy thanks for your reply, could please say how can i find the full Name of my Barcode file by right-clicking? (if you mean that i have to look in to Windows/Fonts Folder then i have done it alrdy and tested with other names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a ttf file the name you use for the font (after the #) is the font name. That can be, but is not necessarilly the same as the file name.

For example.

Our game uses some custom Victorian style fonts.  One of these is ephinol.ttf.

If I right click the ephinol.ttf file in file explorer and choose preview I see one of the fonts dialogs which includes examples of the font in different sizes.

At the top is the full name of the font.

Which is Ephinol WF.

Hence I would use #Ephinol WF rather than #Ephinol

However, I don't do that.

What I do at the moment is I install the font file.  I then do not need to use pack notation to use the font. I do this to guarantee no memory leak.

Otherwise I'd want to use a full file path or another work round ( see link ).

It's quite a small memory leak but it's per use.

https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/746

[image]